# Excel formula to find a particular sheet of a workbook from another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking up one workbook (`Figuresmaster`) to pull financial figures into another workbook (`AreaBudgets`). I have the below lookup formula working (in `AreaBudgets`).

```
=IF(ISNA(
    VLOOKUP($C15,'(directory_path)\[Figuresmaster.xlsx]JULY2015'!$1:$1048576,12,FALSE)),
    0,
    VLOOKUP($C15,'(directory_path)\[Figuresmaster.xlsx]JULY2015'!$1:$1048576,12,FALSE))
```

I would like to now have a way of automatically finding the right month's sheet from workbook (`Figuresmaster`) instead to typing it into the formulas; e.g., a replacement for `July2015` in above formula). 
`July2015` is the sheet name.  I need to be able to add sheets into `Figuresmaster` and not affect the formulas.

I am hoping for a formula to direct to either the sheet name `July2015` or a cell, say `A1`, in each sheet.

I hope this makes sense, as I need this sheet to work.

Comment: It’s not crystal clear; especially not the second-to-last sentence.  What is “the right month’s sheet”?  I am confused by the fact that you are talking about “July2015” even though you have posted this in August 2015.  Do you mean *the previous month’s sheet*?  Do you mean that you want to put the `Figuresmaster` sheet name (`July2015`) into ***a*** cell in `AreaBudgets`, and then have all the formulas in `AreaBudgets` use it?  And what are you saying about “A1 in each sheet”?

Comment: Your formula is (essentially) `=IF(ISERROR(something), 0, that_same_something)`.  That can be hard to maintain (i.e., to modify, when needed, while maintaining consistency), especially if somebody else needs to take responsibility for your files.  That can be simplified to `=IFERROR(something, 0)`.

Comment: In the workbook (Figuresmaster) i have a worksheet for every months figures. i would like be able to get workbook (Areabudgets) to automatically pick up which sheet it wants to reference from. instead of having to type each month into the formula's.   =IF(ISNA(
    VLOOKUP($C15,'(directory_path)\[Figuresmaster.xlsx]JULY2015'!$1:$1048576,12,FALSE)),
    0,
    VLOOKUP($C15,'(directory_path)\[Figuresmaster.xlsx]JULY2015'!$1:$1048576,12,FALSE))

Comment: essentially replacing JULY2015 in the formula above with a look up function to find the right worksheet.

Comment: Am i able to attach an example of the 2 workbooks on here?